# Back button customisation in apple watch?

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-watch

I am designing app such that user has to enter the pin from home screen and show Accounts menus. When the user clicks back the user should logout and page to be navigated to the home screen. As of now on, the clicking of home button it is showing pin controller. But I want to navigate to Home screen. How to achieve this?